# how to cluster a 3d array in python?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scipy, cluster-computing, cluster-analysis

I have to cluster a 3d array that looks like this

```
a=([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[1,4,7],[2,5,9],[3,6,8]]])
```

Imagine that this array represents the coordinates of a triangle in a time series, so the first 2d array represents the coordinates of the vertices in the first frame, the second array represents the coordinates in the second frame and so on. 
I need to cluster the position of this triangle in time, but the cluster algorithms of scikit -learn only work on 2d array. I have performed a reshape of the 3d array to obtain this

```
b=([[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9],[1,4,7,2,5,9,3,6,8]])
```

but the performance of the cluster algorithms are poor (please note that the triangle is an example, I have to cluster the position of a much more complex figure so the dimensionality of the points in the 2d array is very high). 
So I was wondering if there are other method to cluster a 3d array beside the reshape and dimensionality reduction techniques. I've read that converting the 3d array in a distance matrix could be a solution but I really don't know how to do this. If anyone has any kind of advice on how to do this or any other advice on how to solve this problem, I will really appreciate the help!

Comment: If you pass a 3d array it will returns    "ValueError: Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2"

Comment: With which estimator?

Comment: thanks for your answer, this is the code that i'm using                                       kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=25, random_state=0).fit(Y)

Answer (score 0):

The clustering algorthm works with this format for a matrix: `n_samples, n_features`
So in your case your n_sample is your position in time and your n_features is your coordinate. I'm assuming you are trying to find the average location of your shapes across time. I would advise for this type of task to calculate the center point of your shape. Like this no matter the shape you have one point in the middle of the object to track across time. It would make a bit more sense than to try to track all corners on the object which I assume can rotate.

Hope it helps!